# How do I convert pandas.series.groupby() table from count to percent frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, series

I have a small program that I am using to try to calculate a percent frequency on a series within ranges. I'm having success generating a table with the counts of all values within the given ranges, but I am having trouble finding a way, if it exists, to display the counts as percentages of the total number of values. I've included the code below and my current output below that.

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('HmEqty.xlsx')

bad = data["BAD"]
loan = data["LOAN"]
mortdue = data["MORTDUE"]
value = data["VALUE"]
yoj = data["YOJ"]
derog = data["DEROG"]
delinq = data["DELINQ"]
clage = data["CLAGE"]
ninq = data["NINQ"]
clno = data["CLNO"]
debtinc = data["DEBTINC"]


group = loan.groupby(pd.cut(loan, np.arange((loan.min()-100), 
     (loan.max()+100), 500))).count()
print(group)
```

Output:

```
LOAN
(1600, 2100]     2
(2100, 2600]     3
(2600, 3100]     5
(3100, 3600]     3
(3600, 4100]     8
(4100, 4600]    10
(4600, 5100]    24
(5100, 5600]    23
(5600, 6100]    24
Name: LOAN, dtype: int64
```

Is there a method I can use to display the percentage rather than the count? Should I just be performing a second operation on the new DataFrame? If so, how should I go about this?

Comment: Could you share your file, please?

Comment: why not just divide by the length of the dataframe? or do you want frequency per group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize`:

```
s = pd.cut(loan, np.arange((loan.min()-100), (loan.max()+100), 500))
out = s.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Or:

```
s1 = loan.groupby(s).size()
out = s1.div(s1.sum())
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(123)

data = pd.DataFrame({
         'LOAN':np.random.randint(17, 65, 50) * 100
})

loan = data["LOAN"]
s = pd.cut(loan, np.arange((loan.min()-100), (loan.max()+100), 500))
out = s.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
print (out)
(1600, 2100]    0.155556
(2100, 2600]    0.066667
(2600, 3100]    0.066667
(3100, 3600]    0.088889
(3600, 4100]    0.088889
(4100, 4600]    0.088889
(4600, 5100]    0.244444
(5100, 5600]    0.111111
(5600, 6100]    0.088889
Name: LOAN, dtype: float64
```

---

```
s1 = loan.groupby(s).size()
print (s1)
LOAN
(1600, 2100]     7
(2100, 2600]     3
(2600, 3100]     3
(3100, 3600]     4
(3600, 4100]     4
(4100, 4600]     4
(4600, 5100]    11
(5100, 5600]     5
(5600, 6100]     4
Name: LOAN, dtype: int64

out = s1.div(s1.sum())
print (out)
LOAN
(1600, 2100]    0.155556
(2100, 2600]    0.066667
(2600, 3100]    0.066667
(3100, 3600]    0.088889
(3600, 4100]    0.088889
(4100, 4600]    0.088889
(4600, 5100]    0.244444
(5100, 5600]    0.111111
(5600, 6100]    0.088889
Name: LOAN, dtype: float64
```